# ROS Answers SE migration: PCD to Octree

Tags: pcl, octomap, octomap-mapping, pcd, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a registered point-cloud as PCD file. I want to convert it into octree representation. There are two ways I could go. The first one is by using PCL. The second method by using octomap. Is there any difference between them? Which one should I choose?
How could it be done using octomap?

Greetings

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66319/pcd-to-octree/) by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arczi](https://answers.ros.org/users/21104/arczi/) on 2014-12-13**:
Have you got any answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First used pcl to publish a point cloud from the pcd file and then used octomap to get the octree

```
<launch>
<node pkg = "pcl_ros" type = "pcd_to_pointcloud" name = "show_pointcloud" args = "xyz.pcd _frame_id:=/world" output="screen" /
<node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server">
    <param name="resolution" value="0.4" />
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="world" />
    <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
    <param name="sensor_model/max_range" value="100" />
    <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/cloud_pcd" />
</node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [swethmandava](https://answers.ros.org/users/26039/swethmandava/) with karma: 102 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2